# como puedo recorrer un fetch desde otra funcion para poder agregar componentes

Tags: javascript, fetch

Quiero reccorer un fetch (lo que me devuelve ) para poder despues generar componentes en un div pero no se como hacer para que el metodo foreach entienda que es una coleccion no se si es por que no estoy poniendo correctamente que es lo que me tiene que devolver

----------------fecth que quiero consumir despues--------------
const apiurl ="https://localhost:44302/All";

```
export const GetAllFilms=(callback)=>{
    return fetch(apiurl).then((response)=>
    {
        if(response.ok)
        return response.json()
    }).then((body)=>{
        console.log(body);
        callback(body);
        
    });

}
```

donde lo quiero consumir recorriendo la respuesta como si fuera un array

```
import { GetAllFilms } from '../services/ServicePelicula.js'

 const renderCarrusel = (json)=>{
    const carusel = document.getElementById('carrusel-pelis')
    carusel.innerHTML+=carusel(json.poster);
}
const renderTarjeta = (json)=>{
    const carusel = document.getElementById('tarjetas')
    carusel.innerHTML+=tarjeta(json.poster,json.titulo,json.sinopsis,json.peliculaId);
}
const chargeInitCarrusel=()=>{
      const films= GetAllFilms();
```

aca es dodonde quiero recorrerla con un forech

```
      films.forEach(element => {
        renderCarrusel(element)
        console.log(element)
    });
}
```

Luego de intentar hacer eso me dice que films.forEach (is not a function)

Comment: guarda los datos en una variable global ...

Comment: y como exactamente puedo hacer eso , soy realmente muy nuevo en javascript

Comment: declara una variable fuera de todo .... fuera de funciones y clases ...

Comment: `const apiurl ="https://localhost:44302/All";

    export const GetAllFilms=()=>{ 
     return fetch(apiurl).then((response)=>
        {
            if(response.ok)
            return response.json()
        }).then((body)=>
        console.log(body);
       AllFilms=body;
        return body;
    });

    
    }
    export var  AllFilms=[];
`
Algo como esto? igual me devuelve como un arreglo vacio pero en el debugger me muestra que si tiene elementos

Comment: si espero eso esta tu const tiene un export y no has aclarado la estructura fe rus archivos. ???

Comment: y eso es una cosntante solo la lenas una vez???

Comment: sisi solamente la lleno una ves proe ya varias cosas seguro es algo idiota y es por mi falta de comprensión en el lenguaje

Comment: para nada no digas eso; aquí nadie nació sabiendo, todos fuimos ignorantes en algun punto y venimos en busca de ayuda... solo que no soy experto en node y react que me parece estas implementando pero en javascript con una variable en el root del codigo se considera global y puedes acceder a ella en cualquier sitio ....